# Definition of conditional cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with support on $[0,2]$, What is $F(x/X<1)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What does the notation $F(... > 2)$ mean? That is not common.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the question, I think it is $\frac{F(x)}{P(X<1)}$, but I do not know why.